# How can i insert data in mysql using react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have done validation using react-hook-form but wanted to know how to insert this data in database using express js. I am new to react js. How can we insert data using axios post request to mysql database?

Myform.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
export const Enrollment = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className='container '>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div class='mb-3 mt-5'>
          <h2>Enrollment Percentage</h2>
          <label for='exampleFormControlInput1' class='form-label'>
            Program Name
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            class='form-control w-25'
            name='program'
            id='exampleFormControlInput1'
            {...register('Programname', {
              required: true,
              pattern: {
                value: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                message: 'Only characters allowed',
              },
            })}
          />
          {errors.Programname && errors.Programname.type === 'required' && (
            // <span role="alert">This is required</span>
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> This is required</div>
          )}

          {errors.Programname && errors.Programname.type === 'pattern' && (
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> Only characters allowed</div>
          )}
        </div>

        <div class='mb-3 w-25 '>
          <label for='exampleFormControlTextarea1' class='form-label'>
            Program Code
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            class='form-control'
            id='exampleFormControlTextarea1'
            name='programcode'
            {...register('Programcode', {
              required: true,
              pattern: { value: /^[0-9\b]+$/, message: 'Only number allowed' },
            })}
          />
          {errors.Programcode && errors.Programcode.type === 'required' && (
            // <span role="alert">This is required</span>
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> This is required</div>
          )}

          {errors.Programcode && errors.Programcode.type === 'pattern' && (
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> Only numbers allowed</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div class='mb-3 w-25'>
          <label for='exampleFormControlTextarea1' class='form-label'>
            Number of seats sanctioned
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            class='form-control'
            id='exampleFormControlTextarea1'
            name='seats'
            {...register('seats', {
              required: true,
              pattern: { value: /^[0-9\b]+$/, message: 'Only Number allowed' },
            })}
          />
          {errors.seats && errors.seats.type === 'required' && (
            // <span role="alert">This is required</span>
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> This is required</div>
          )}

          {errors.seats && errors.seats.type === 'pattern' && (
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> Only numbers allowed</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div class='mb-3 w-25'>
          <label for='exampleFormControlTextarea1' class='form-label'>
            Number of Students admitted
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            class='form-control'
            id='exampleFormControlTextarea1'
            name='students'
            {...register('students', {
              required: true,
              pattern: { value: /^[0-9\b]+$/, message: 'Only number allowed' },
            })}
          />
          {errors.students && errors.students.type === 'required' && (
            // <span role="alert">This is required</span>
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> This is required</div>
          )}

          {errors.students && errors.students.type === 'pattern' && (
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> Only numbers allowed</div>
          )}
        </div>

        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary me-md-2'>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const onSubmit = async(data) => {
  await axios.post("api_calling", data).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.message) {
      console.log(response.data.message);
    } else {
      console.log("failed to post data");
    }
  });
  reset();
};
```